# Find the average value of the function $f(x)=6x^3$ on the interval $2 \le x \le 6$

Tags: calculus

I am completely lost on how to solve this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For any function $f$,
the average value of $f$
on $[a, b]$
is
$\frac1{b-a}\int_a^b f(x)dx$.

Comment: Notice that "integrate from a to b, then divide by the "size of the interval", b- a", is the "continuous" equivalent of adding a list of n numbers and dividing by the "size of the list", n.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mean of this function is given by $\frac{1}{6-2}\int_{2}^{6}6x^3dx=\frac{3}{2}(\frac{6^4}{4}-\frac{2^4}{4})$

You can look at the following link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_a_function